Why gitlab ci fails with no error and how can I fix it?
Here is the content of .gitlab-ci.yml file:
stages:
  - deploy

deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - ssh-keyscan -H 37.152.183.16 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to server...."
    - git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@37.152.183.16 "cd /var/www/api && git pull origin master"
  only:
    - master

It fails with no error, here is the log:

See? I cannot find any error there. Any idea what's wrong and how can I fix it?
